# ESP32 - NimBLE increase throughput

Tags: esp32, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm doing a OTA DFU with two ESP32 to upgrade a STM32 uC. This works out reliable so far, but the transmission speed over BLE between the two STM32 is really slow and so the DFU takes up to 10min, which is way too much.

I'm using the NimBLE Stack and the ESP-IDF framework and I get a througput of roughly 80byte/s by using the following function with a callback:

```
void sendData(uint8_t *data, uint16_t len)
{
    can_data_be_sent = false;
    ble_gattc_write_flat(connection_handle_t, chr->chr.val_handle, data, len, ble_cb, NULL);
}

...

static int ble_cb(uint16_t conn_handle,
                     const struct ble_gatt_error *error,
                     struct ble_gatt_attr *attr,
                     void *arg)
{
    can_data_be_sent = true;

    return 0;
}
```

I send data of length 8 at once, so there is theoretically a way to increase the speed by using a MTU up to 512 bytes, but it seems, that there is something else I'm missing here, that slows down the whole thing. sendData() is called every 1ms and when I don't use the flag can_data_be_sent, I get around 1kbyte/s (but with crc errors after receving), so the transmission seems to take around 80ms and I really don't see why.

Any Ideas? Normally there should also be a connection interval, but I cannot find this in the SDK_CONFIG for NimBLE.

**Edit:** I see, that I can only send something every 100ms, so that seems like a timeout is blocking it, but I cannot see anything like that:

[image]

Comment: Is the receive side writing to flash?  This can take a while.  I would suggest sending a block size of data if you can.

Comment: It is not, the whole firmware is buffered in the RAM and after completion of the transfer and CRC check it gets written to the flash. It seems the transmission of a packet is direktly 100ms, so it must be somewhere a timeout limitting the transfer.